# SSAS Tabular Table Processing Memory issue

Tags: memory, ssas, olap, tabular

When I'am trying to edit SSAS Tabular project using with Visual Studio 2015 in table properties section,I am getting error like 
"The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application. If using a 32-bit version of the product, consider upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory available on the machine." 
when counted row is equal to almost 5 million row.

Is there any permanent solution for the issue?

Comment: Sometimes the problem is not about RAM, it is because of complicated formula in calculated column... check your recently added calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

These errors can be caused by an incorrect memory setting in SSAS.

According to MSDN Memory Properties document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174514.aspx

Values between 1 and 100 represent percentages of Total Physical Memory or Virtual Address Space, whichever is less. Values over 100 represent memory limits in bytes.

If the admin thinks a value above 100 is in KBs or MBs, the admin may put in a setting that is way too low for SSAS to operate properly, giving this "not enough memory" error when the server still has a lot of memory available.

The solution is to make the memory settings change to give a proper value to the memory limits in either percentage of server memory, or in bytes.